# AVAudioPlayer not resuming when hitting stop button

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to create an app that will play some audio files.  I was hoping to stream the audio from a web server, but so far am placing an mp3 directly into the project as I don't know how to link to http urls.

I have created a stop button and my understanding is that if you press stop and then play again, the mp3 file should resume from where it has stopped.  That's not happening for me.  Any clues as to what I have done wrong please?  I have also tried using pause as well with no change.  Many thanks in advance.  The code from my .h file is below.

Also, what do I need to do if I want to have multiple audio files?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
NSURL *songURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hustle"     ofType:@"mp3"]];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
player.volume = 0.5;
[player play];

}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
[player stop];
}

- (IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender {
player.volume = volumeSlider.value;

}


@end
```

Here is the edited .m file with the array:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//NSURL *songURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hustle"     ofType:@"mp3"]];
//player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
//player.volume = 0.5;

songsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hustle", @"hustle2", nil];
NSUInteger currentTrackNumber;
currentTrackNumber=0;

}

- (IBAction)startPlaying
{
if (player) {
    [player stop];
    player = nil;
}
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle   mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[songsArray objectAtIndex:currentTrackNumber]] ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player1 successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
if (flag) {
    if (currentTrackNumber < [songsArray count] - 1) {
        currentTrackNumber ++;
        if (player) {
            [player stop];
            player = nil;
        }
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[songsArray objectAtIndex:currentTrackNumber]] ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
    }
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

[player play];

}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
[player stop];
}

- (IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender {
player.volume = volumeSlider.value;

}

@end
```

Comment: you should pause it instead of stoping, `[player pause];` then you have to play again to resume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Write the code like this, when you click on the pause button the audio stopped then click on the play button the audio will resumed where the audio stopped.     



- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        NSURL *songURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hustle"     ofType:@"mp3"]];
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
        player.volume = 0.5;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

        [player play];

    }

    - (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
        [player stop];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh - that fixed my problem a treat!  Is there any guidance you can give me if I want to play more than 1 audio file please?  I would like to add a couple more audio files to my project.

Answer (score 0):

@user3934210

Take  a array in .h file  and write protocol  delegate for Player

"AVAudioPlayerDelegate>"

```
NSMutableArray *songsArray;
```

in .m files

```
Add all the .mp3 songs to the array in viewDidLoad

songsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@“A”,@“B”,@“C”,nil]; //replace your files

then take one Integer value to find the current song
    NSUInteger currentTrackNumber;

and set the currentTrackNumber=0 in viewDidLoad,

then copy the below code

- (IBAction)startPlaying
{
    if (player) {
        [player stop];
        player = nil;
    }
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[songsArray objectAtIndex:currentTrackNumber]] ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player1 successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        if (currentTrackNumber < [songsArray count] - 1) {
            currentTrackNumber ++;
            if (player) {
                [player stop];
                player = nil;
            }
            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[songsArray objectAtIndex:currentTrackNumber]] ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does all this code go in the .h file?  Sorry, finding it hard to read as you have added in normal text within the code box.  Thanks for helping out again.

Comment: Ok, have added in the array stuff, but have lots of errors, in particular Xcode isn't liking the "" where I've put in the filenames.  Also, keeps saying use of undeclared identifier 'currentTrackNumber'.  Thanks again, I am starting to learn this!  My .m file is in the original post above.

Comment: declare  NSUInteger currentTrackNumber; in .h file

Comment: Ok, I have no error messages now.  It all builds, but no music is playing.  How do I get my play button to play a track please?  Thanks again!